# AngularJs - ui-router nested view not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having difficulty showing a nested view

**1. Base App**

> ```
> "name": "app",
> "abstract": true,
> "url": "",
> "views": {
>   "root": {
>     "templateUrl": "layout.html",
>     "controller": "",
>     "controllerAs" : ""
>   },
>   "header@app": {"templateUrl": ""},
>   "nav@app": {"templateUrl": ""},
> ```

**With index page showing:**

> ```
> <div ui-view="root"></div>
> ```

**With layout page showing:**

> ```
> <div ui-view="header"></div>
> <div ui-view="nav"></div> 
> <div ui-view="content"></div>
> ```

**2. content state example**

> ```
> "name": "app.content",
> "url": "/content",
> "views": {
>   "content@app": {
>     "templateUrl": "sample1.html",
>     "controller": "",
>     "controllerAs" : ""
>   }
> }
> ```

**3. another content state example**

> ```
> "name": "app.content.inbox",
> "url": "/inbox",
> "views": {
>   "content@app": {
>     "templateUrl": "sample2.html",
>     "controller": "",
>     "controllerAs": ""
>   }
> }
> ```

**Up until this point everything works fine**

**Sample2.html has a nested view and the html for that page looks like this:**

> ```
> <div ui-view="folder"></div>
> ```

**And the state being this:**

> ```
> "name": "app.content.inbox.folder",
> "url": "/inbox/:folder",
> "views": {
>   "folder@app.content": {
>     "templateUrl": "folder.html",
>     "controller": "",
>     "controllerAs": ""
>   }
> }
> ```

**I am not getting the folder.html nested view. Can anyone see my error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state should be like this *(I commented original incorrect parts, changes are below them)*:

```
"name": "app.content.inbox.folder",
//"url": "/inbox/:folder",
"url": "/:folder",
"views": {
  //"folder@app.content": {
  "folder@app.content.inbox": {
    "templateUrl": "folder.html",
    "controller": "",
    "controllerAs": ""
  }
}
```

In fact, if the view targets named view of its parent even this would work

```
"views": {
  //"folder@app.content": {
  // "folder@app.content.inbox": { // correct but redundant
  "folder": {                    // that is enough, parent will be searched by default
```

Comment: Your first suggestion ('folder@app.content.inbox') worked. However, only when I nested folder within the inbox state. which kind of sucks as now I will need to load its dependencies in that state as well, as opposed to wanting to keep folder & its dependencies separate.

Comment: Not sure what could I do more here for you :( ... or?